# Setting Up Flex Project with Coldfusion

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, crossdomain.xml

We recently built a new dev server for flex builder and installed coldfusion 8. We currently have everything working on our old server using coldfusion 7. We copied the services-config.xml and our project over to the new server. It compiled fine, I updated all references to the new server. When I try to run the flex application I receive the following error:

Warning: Failed to load policy file from http://localhost/crossdomain.xml

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to http://localhost/flex2gateway/ halted - not permitted from file://ourServer/folder/ourProject/bin-debug/ourProject.swf

We created a valid crossdomain.xml file on the localhost (which I wouldnt think would be necessary since everything is on the same server)

Any idea what I can do or look at to resolve the problem?

Comment: Is the file you deployed named crossdomain.xml or cross-domain.xml? It needs to be the former.

Comment: Thanks, typed it in wrong, it was correct in the implentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it... I had to set the "Output Folder URL" which was set to blank. When I went to debug the program it loaded it into the browser as  \myserver\myproject\ ... when I set the Output Folder URL it loads as http://outputFolderURL and corrects the problem.