# Flex RemoteObject Source not found

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, cfc, remoteobject, file-not-found

Our flex project, which works fine in its current environment with coldfusion 7 single server.

We moved this project to Coldfusion 8 multi server, and updated the remoteobject paths relative to the web root.

The error we now receive is

faultCode:Server.Processing faultString:'Unable to invoke CFC - Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface myProject.cf.main.' faultDetail:'For details, turn on Robust Exception Information in the ColdFusion Administrator'

The path to the cfc's from the webroot is is myProject/cf/main.cfc ... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335913/setting-up-flex-project-with-coldfusion). That solution solves this too.